# How to configure ELB for two different ports in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-cdk

I am having an elastic load balancer serving traffic to an EC2 instance. I have an application running on port 443 and it runs just fine.

Now I want to run another application on the EC2 instance on port 444. I want to be able to run the first application by hitting port 443 and the second application by hitting port 444.

Somehow I cant manage to add port 444 to the load balancer in CDK. I am doing something like this.

```
 const appLoadbalancer = new elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, `${props.type}AppLoadBalancer`, {
            vpc: vpc,
            vpcSubnets: subnets,
            internetFacing: true,
        });

        const httpsListener = appLoadbalancer.addListener(`${props.type}HTTPSListener`, {
            port: 443,
            open: true,
            certificates: [props.certificate]
        });

        httpsListener.addTargets(`${props.type}HTTPSTarget`, {
            port: 443,
            targets: [autoscalingGroup],
            healthCheck: {
                enabled: true,
                healthyHttpCodes: "200,302"
            }
        });

        const httpsListener2 = appLoadbalancer.addListener(`${props.type}HTTPSListener2`, {
            port: 444,
            protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
            open: true,
            certificates: [props.certificate]
        });

        httpsListener2.addTargets(`${props.type}HTTPSTarget2`, {
            port: 444,
            protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
            targets: [autoscalingGroup],
            healthCheck: {
                enabled: true,
                healthyHttpCodes: "200,302"
            }
        });
```

Everything is working just fine if it set it up only for port 443. But When I try the above i get something like:

```
Error: Cannot add AutoScalingGroup to 2nd Target Group
```

I dont know what is meant by this and how to fix it in cdk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a solution like this:

```
 const appLoadbalancer = new elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, `${props.type}AppLoadBalancer`, {
            vpc: vpc,
            vpcSubnets: subnet,
            internetFacing: true,
        });

        const tg1 = new elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(this, "tg1", {
            vpc: vpc,
            protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS})
        const tg2 = new elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(this, "tg2", {vpc: vpc,
        protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS, port: 444})

        const httpsListener = appLoadbalancer.addListener(`${props.type}HTTPSListener`, {
            port: 443,
            protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
            open: true,
            certificates: [props.certificate]
        });
        httpsListener.addTargetGroups("RestTarget", {
            targetGroups: [tg1]
        });

        const httpsListener2 = appLoadbalancer.addListener(`${props.type}HTTPSListener2`, {
            port: 444,
            protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
            open: true,
            certificates: [props.certificate]
        });
        httpsListener2.addTargetGroups("RestTarget", {
            targetGroups: [tg2]
        });

        const ServiceAsg = autoscalingGroup.node.defaultChild as autoscaling.CfnAutoScalingGroup
        ServiceAsg.targetGroupArns = [tg1.targetGroupArn, tg2.targetGroupArn]
```